# Detecting circular references in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE X (
    A SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
    B SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
    C SOMETYPE NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (A,B),
    FOREIGN KEY (A,C) REFERENCES X (A,B)
);
```

The entities stored in `X` are hierarchically organized: If a row `(A1,B1,C1)` exists and `C1 IS NOT NULL` then it is considered to be a "child" of `(A1,C1,C2)` whatever `C2` is. Since an item cannot descend from itself, I would like to make it illegal that circular hierarchical sequences exist:

```
-- legal
INSERT INTO X (A1,B1,NULL);
INSERT INTO X (A1,B2,B1);
INSERT INTO X (A1,B3,B2);
INSERT INTO X (A1,B4,B2);

-- currently legal, but I want to make it illegal
UPDATE X SET C = B1 WHERE B = B1;  /* B1-B1 */
UPDATE X SET C = B2 WHERE B = B1;  /* B1-B2-B1 */
UPDATE X SET C = B3 WHERE B = B1;  /* B1-B2-B3-B1 */
UPDATE X SET C = B4 WHERE B = B1;  /* B1-B2-B4-B1 */
UPDATE X SET C = B2 WHERE B = B2;  /* B2-B2 */
UPDATE X SET C = B3 WHERE B = B2;  /* B2-B3-B2 */
UPDATE X SET C = B4 WHERE B = B2;  /* B2-B4-B2 */
UPDATE X SET C = B3 WHERE B = B3;  /* B3-B3 */
UPDATE X SET C = B4 WHERE B = B4;  /* B4-B4 */
```

How do I do this?

---

Alternatively, I could add a field representing the "level" in the hierarchy to the table:

```
CREATE TABLE X (
    A SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
    B SOMETYPE NOT NULL,
    C SOMETYPE NULL,
    LEVEL INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (A,B),
    FOREIGN KEY (A,C) REFERENCES X (A,B)
);
```

Then I would like to require that `LEVEL` be `0` when `C IS NULL`, and `parent's LEVEL + 1` otherwise.

---

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Which DBMS ? SQL Server 2000/2005/2008, Oracle, MySQL, etc. ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008... I didn't think this should be relevant.

Comment: Of course it matters. What if a new feature would solve the problem?

Comment: can you provide actual data examples that would go in this table?  i have a hard time visualizing a business scenario where this could be applicable.

Comment: @foampile: I am making a tool for representing arbitrary business processes as a series of transactions that manipulate documents in prespecified formats. Basically, a metadata database whose contents fully specify an ERP from a transactional point of view. Nowadays, I am not using SQL Server (or any SQL DBMS) anymore. I am making my own DBMS.

Comment: so something like a process flow markup language structured in tabular format.  i like that -- done something quite similar recently

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check for circular references i have used a trigger and recursive CTE:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgIU_X_CheckCircularReferences
ON dbo.X
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Results TABLE ([Exists] BIT);

    WITH CteHierarchy
    AS
    (
        SELECT  x.A, x.B, X.C, 1 AS [Type]
        FROM    inserted i
        JOIN    X x ON i.A = x.A AND i.C = x.B
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  x.A, x.B, X.C, 2 AS [Type]
        FROM    CteHierarchy i
        JOIN    X x ON i.A = x.A AND i.C = x.B
        WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (
                SELECT  *
                FROM    inserted a
                WHERE   a.A = x.A AND a.B = x.B
        )   
    )
    INSERT  @Results ([Exists])
    SELECT  TOP(1) 1
    FROM    CteHierarchy h
    JOIN    X x ON h.A = x.A AND h.C = x.B
    OPTION(MAXRECURSION 1000);

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Results)
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RAISERROR('Circular references detected', 16, 1);
    END
END
GO
```

Now, we can run some tests:

```
--Test 1 - OK
PRINT '*****Test 1 - OK*****';
SELECT * FROM X;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE  X 
SET     C = 'B1'
WHERE   B = 'B4';

SELECT * FROM X;

--This transaction can be commited without problems
--but I will cancel all modification so we can run the second test
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
PRINT '*****End of test 1*****';    
GO

--Test 2 - NOT OK
PRINT '*****Test 2 - NOT OK*****';
SELECT * FROM X;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE  X 
SET     C = 'B1'
WHERE   B = 'B1';

--Useless in this case (test 2 & test 3)
--Read section [If a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION is issued in a trigger] from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181299.aspx
SELECT * FROM X;
--Useless
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
--Useless
PRINT '*****End of test 2*****';        
GO

PRINT '*****Test 3 - NOT OK*****';
SELECT * FROM X;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE  X 
SET     C = 'B4'
WHERE   B = 'B1';
GO
```

Results:

```
*****Test 1 - OK*****

(4 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)

(4 row(s) affected)
*****End of test 1*****
*****Test 2 - NOT OK*****

(4 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgIU_X_CheckCircularReferences, Line 34
Circular references detected
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
*****Test 3 - NOT OK*****

(4 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure trgIU_X_CheckCircularReferences, Line 34
Circular references detected
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

For the second test, you can see how this trigger has canceled (`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`) the transaction and, after UPDATE, nothing has been executed (in current *batch*).