# Detecting circular references among rows in a SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting circular references in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540760/detecting-circular-references-in-sql)

I need a way to easily detect circular reference for a table with employee/manager relation in SQL Server. Has anyone already written this query?

Comment: Do you want to do this as a trigger when inserting?  Or, are you looking for an "after the fact" type of report?

Comment: which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
select ID
from yourtable a
where exists (select *
              from yourtable b
              where a.SourceID = b.TargetID and
                    a.TargetID = b.SourceID)
```

Of course, that will not detect large circles (i.e. `a --> b --> c --> a`).  For that, you need something stronger, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7541395/102937).

Comment: Didn't know that code was measured in units of "strength"

Comment: And I didn't know kiwis had hair.