# SQL get circles in table

Tags: sql, database, geometry

how can I find circles in sql table ?
for example if this is my table:

```
From To
  x  y
  y  z
  z  x
```

I want to get x->y->z->x

Iam using SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting circular references in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540760/detecting-circular-references-in-sql)

Comment: I don't understand what is it ? , I want the query as pure sql query

Comment: What did you try? you can't expect us to write code for you :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? ("*SQL*" is just a query language, not a DBMS product)

Comment: Iam using  PostgreSQL , and Iam writing my program in c (but I can't use c to manipulate data )

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to get your pattern.
Try the script below and customize it to fit your need.

```
create table table1(
    [from] varchar(max),
    [to] varchar(max)
);
insert into table1([From], [To])
 values( 'x',  'y'),
       ( 'y',  'z'),
       ( 'z',  'x');

--select [From], [To] 
--from table1

DECLARE @first_val char(1);

--find the first value
select top(1) @first_val = [From] 
from table1;

--recursive cte 
;with cte([From], [To] ) as (
    select [From] , [To] 
    from table1
    where [From]=@first_val
    union all
    select c.[From] +'->'+t.[From] , t.[To] 
    from cte c
    join table1 t on t.[From] = c.[To]
    where t.[From] != @first_val
)
select [From]+'->'+[To] 
from cte
where [To]=@first_val;

--drop table table1;
```